# Whats the right approach for making .Net Framework library project compatible with both .Net Framework Rest App and .Net Core Rest App

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0

I have library project build in .Net Framework 4.8(eg. *CoreRetailLibrary*)  , with lots of references to **System.Web** package.
Our plan is to modernize the Rest API's that are referencing *CoreRetailLibrary* , from  .Net Framework to .Net Core.
After reading lots of blogs , I had a painful realization that it is not possible in the the normal way unless we continue to use .Net Framework for the API.
I would love to move to .Net Core so that I can use the Microservice, Cloud and Docker  capability.

Is there anything apart from rewriting oe duplicating the entire CoreRetailLibrary to .Net Core , which is still referenced by other Projects using .Net Framework.

Is there a middle ground where I can make CoreRetailLibrary compatible with both .Net Core and .Net Framework.

Please provide some guidance .

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Chandan, I'm afraid not. .NET framework are quite different from the .NET CORE, you need firstly follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) to use .NET Portability Analyzer to analysis the compatibility then you can know the next step for how to deal with the migration.

Comment: Thanks @Rena .  Our problem was we have few references to the System.Web.HTTPContext in the core library files. Since it was built 10 years ago Microsoft allowed this in external Helper class files and Coders exploited it.    we will be fixing our apps to move HttpContext references to the webapps so that the  CoreRetailLibrary is just an set of plain classes. This will help us ease the migration.